# Fade away title bar like on the FaceTime mac app

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

How does Apple fade away the title bar in the FaceTime mac application? I believe QuickTime X also does the same thing. I would like to do something similar in an app I have planned. Does anyone know how I would do the same thing in my own mac application?